# Read plot values interactively (with a targetting line) in a Shiny app

Tags: r, plot, shiny, interactive

I'm essentially trying to replicate the behavior of the graph on [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-interactive-unit-circle.html) site in a Shiny app.

That is, I want to create an interactive graph, where by hovering the mouse cursor over the graph, you move a "targeting line" along the x-axis. Then, according to the position of the targeting line, the y-values of the plot lines on the graph are displayed on the intersection point of the targeting line and the plot lines. (I was going to post an illustrative figure, but it appears I don't have enough reputation for that yet.)

I've managed to get the application to work. In my current implementation I'm using the `hover` option in `plotOutput` to get the location of the cursor on the plot, and then adding a targeting line using `abline` to a new plot. Along with `points` and `text` to add the y-values on the plot.

The issue I'm having is that the targeting line starts to severely lag behind the actual mouse cursor after moving around for a while. I think this is due to having to redraw the entire plot every time the mouse hovering position updates (currently every 500 ms when the cursor is moving, since I'm using `hoverOpts(delayType = "throttle")`). The rendering just isn't fast enough to keep up with the mouse movement. I was wondering if anybody has an idea on how to get around this problem.

Runnable code for an example of the Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

trigWaves <- function(A = 1, ...) {
  xval <- seq(0, 2*pi, len = 201)
  sinx <- A * sin(xval); cosx <- A * cos(xval)

  plot(x = xval, y = sinx, type = 'n', ylab = "f(x)", xlab = "x", ...)
  abline(h = A * c(-1, 0, 1), lty = c(2, 1, 2), col = 'gray')
  abline(v = pi * seq(0, 2, by = 0.5), lty = 2, col = 'gray')
  lines(x = xval, y = sinx, col = 'red')
  lines(x = xval, y = cosx, col = 'blue')
  box()

  invisible(list(x = xval, y = list(sin = sinx, cos = cosx)))
}

# Maximum selectable amplitude
Amax <- 5


runApp(
  # Define UI for application
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(

    # Application title
    headerPanel("Read Function Values Interactively from a Plot"),

    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("amplitude", 
                  "Amplitude:", 
                  min = 1,
                  max = Amax, 
                  value = 2,
                  step = 0.1)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("trigGraph",
                 hover =
                   hoverOpts(
                            id = "plothover",
                         delay = 500,
                     delayType = "throttle"
                   )
                 )

    )
  ),

  # Define server for application
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    A <- reactive(input$amplitude)
    hoverx <- reactiveValues(initial = 2)

    # Hover position
    tx <- reactive({

      # If no previous hover position found, return initial = 0
      if (is.null(hoverx$prev)) return(hoverx$initial)

      # Hover resets to NULL every time the plot is redrawn -
      # If hover is null, then use the previously saved hover value.
      if (is.null(input$plothover)) hoverx$prev else input$plothover$x

    })

    # Function to plot the 'reader line' and the function values
    readLine <- reactive({

       abline(v = tx(), col = 'gray'); box()

       # Plot coordinates for values and points
       pcoords <- list(x = rep(tx(), 2), y = A() * c(sin(tx()), cos(tx())))

       points(pcoords, pch = 16, col = c("red", "blue"))    # points on lines
       text(pcoords, labels = round(pcoords$y, 2), pos = 4) # function values

     })

    # Render the final output graph
    output$trigGraph <- renderPlot({

      # Create base plot
      trigWaves(A = A(), ylim = Amax * c(-1, 1))

      readLine() # Add the reader line and function values

      # Add a legend
      legend(x = 3.5, y = 0.9 * Amax, 
             legend = c("sin(x)", "cos(x)"),
             col = c("red", "blue"), lty = 1)

      # Save the hover position used as the previous position
      hoverx$prev <- tx()

    })

  }), display.mode= "showcase"
)
```

Comment: [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/) has very nice and interactive graphs

Comment: @Andriy Thanks for the link, seems like a really interesting package!

Comment: Check out highCharts in rCharts ! They extends the possibility of using jQuery and JS in Shiny apps to create great visualizations. They don't redraw the plot every time.

Comment: Also look into https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six years later, JavaScript is still the way to go for a graph like this.

Here’s an overview of a couple of different R packages to achieve that,
including dygraphs and highcharts originally mentioned in the comments.

```r
# Goal is to make an interactive crosshair plot with data from this.
trigWaves <- function(x, A = 1, ...) {
  rbind(
    data.frame(x, y = A * sin(x), f = "sin"),
    data.frame(x, y = A * cos(x), f = "cos")
  )
}

xs <- seq(0, 2 * pi, len = 201)
Amax <- 5 # Maximum amplitude -- determines plot range, too.
```

## Plotting methods

### [dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/)

```r
library(dygraphs)

plot_dygraphs = function(data) {
  # Unlike other packages, dygraphs wants wide data
  wide <- data %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
      names_from = f,
      values_from = y
    )
  
  dygraph(wide) %>% 
    dyCrosshair("vertical") %>% 
    dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(-1, 1) * Amax)
}
```

### [highcharter](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/)

```r
library(highcharter)

plot_highcharter = function(data) {
  hchart(data, "line", hcaes(x, y, group = f)) %>%
    hc_xAxis(crosshair = TRUE) %>% 
    hc_yAxis(min = -Amax, max = Amax)
}
```

### [plotly](https://plotly.com/r/)

```r
library(plotly)

plot_plotly = function(data) {
  plot_ly(data) %>%
    add_lines(~ x, ~ y, color = ~ f) %>% 
    layout(
      hovermode = "x",
      spikedistance = -1,
      xaxis = list(
        showspikes = TRUE,
        spikemode = "across"
      ),
      yaxis = list(range = c(-1, 1) * Amax)
    )
}
```

### [c3](http://mrjoh3.github.io/c3/)

```r
library(c3)

plot_c3 = function(data) {
  c3(data, "x", "y", group = "f") %>% 
    c3_line("line") %>% 
    yAxis(min = -Amax, max = Amax) %>% 
    point_options(show = FALSE)
}
```

## Shiny app

All of the packages also integrate with Shiny. Here’s a demo app showcasing them:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("amplitude", "Amplitude:", 0.1, Amax, 1, step = 0.1),
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
      tags$h3("dygraphs"),
      dygraphOutput("dygraphs"),
    ),
    column(6,
      tags$h3("highcharter"),
      highchartOutput("highcharter"),
    ),
    column(6,
      tags$h3("plotly"),
      plotlyOutput("plotly"),
    ),
    column(6,
      tags$h3("c3"),
      c3Output("c3", height = "400px"), # All others have 400px default height
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  waves <- reactive(trigWaves(xs, input$amplitude))
  
  output$dygraphs <- renderDygraph({ plot_dygraphs(waves()) })
  output$highcharter <- renderHighchart({ plot_highcharter(waves()) })
  output$plotly <- renderPlotly({ plot_plotly(waves()) })
  output$c3 <- renderC3({ plot_c3(waves()) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

See it live here: https://mikkmart.shinyapps.io/crosshair/